# BashScript to organize a given txt file

Tags: linux, bash

I have a txt file of single column that I will like to divide into multiple columns and label them.

I've tried what I know, but the division is not what I want.

I have a ivmeasurementff.txt which contains:

```
24.000000
0.003207
0.000002
25.000000
0.003435
0.000002
26.000000
0.003991
0.000002
27.000000
0.003207
0.000002
28.000000
0.003232
0.000002
29.000000
0.003283
```

```
pr -ts" " --columns 2 ivmeasurementff.txt
```

This code just split the column into two

Expected output:

```
Actual Vol  T Vol      Current
24.000000   0.003207   0.000002
25.000000   0.003435   0.000002
26.000000   0.003991   0.000002
```

Actual output:

```
24.000000   0.003435
0.003207    0.000002
0.000002    26.000000
25.000000   0.003991
```

Comment: You should show the script. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix3/upt/ch21_15.htm

Under 21.15.3 it suggests using the -l option

```
pr -ts" " -l1 -3   ivmeasurementff.txt
24.000000 0.003207 0.000002
25.000000 0.003435 0.000002
26.000000 0.003991 0.000002
27.000000 0.003207 0.000002
28.000000 0.003232 0.000002
29.000000 0.003283
```

Quoting:

**21.15.3. Order Lines Across Columns: -l**

Do you want to arrange your data across the columns, so that the first three lines print across the top of each column, the next three lines are the second in each column, and so on, like this?

```
 % pr -l1 -t -3 file1 
Line 1 here Line 2 here Line 3 here
Line 4 here Line 5 here Line 6 here
Line 7 here Line 8 here Line 9 here 
... ... ...
```

Use the -l1 (page length 1 line) and -t (no title) options. Each "page" will be filled by three lines (or however many columns you set). You have to use -t; otherwise, pr will silently ignore any page lengths that don't leave room for the header and footer. That's just what you want if you want data in columns with no headings.

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution with `xargs`:

```
xargs -n 3 < Input-file
```

Or if you are ok with `awk`.

```
awk 'FNR%3==0 && FNR!=1{print val,$0;val="";next} {val=(val?val OFS:"")$0} END{if(val){print val}}' Input_file
```

perl solution:

```
perl -pe 's{\n$}{ } if $. % 3'   Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use `paste` to format it into 3 columns:

```
paste - - - < ivmeasurementff.txt
```

Since there's no header, you have to manually add it:

```
echo "Actual Vol\tT Vol\tCurrent"; paste - - - < ivmeasurementff.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add option `-a` and specify three columns.

```
$ pr -ats" " --columns 3 ivmeasurementff.txt
24.000000 0.003207 0.000002
25.000000 0.003435 0.000002
26.000000 0.003991 0.000002
27.000000 0.003207 0.000002
28.000000 0.003232 0.000002
29.000000 0.003283
```

I'm not sure why this works. Seems like `pr` treats columns as rows in some cases?